# Arduino: detecting buttons pressed inside a while loop

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, arduino

I have been trying to write a code to basically add points to a score whenever I pressed a button while a certain amount of time is running down. The problem I am finding is that it doesn't detect when the button is pressed while the time is decreasing, in fact it can only detect when the time starts to decrease and then it doesn't matter at which state the button is it will continue to add to the score. Anyway here is the main code:

```
void loop() {
  buttonState01 = digitalRead(button01);
  buttonState02 = digitalRead(button02);
  buttonState03 = digitalRead(button03);

if (buttonState01){

time = 3000;
    while(time > 0){
      if (buttonState02){
        score += 10;
        Serial.println(score);
      }
  time--;
Serial.println(time);
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the full code if needed:

```
int button01 = 4;
int button02 = 3;
int button03 = 2;

int buttonState01 = 0;
int buttonState02 = 0;
int buttonState03 = 0;

float time;
int score;

void setup() {
  score = 0;

  time = 0;

  pinMode(button01, INPUT);
  pinMode(button02, INPUT);
  pinMode(button03, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  buttonState01 = digitalRead(button01);
  buttonState02 = digitalRead(button02);
  buttonState03 = digitalRead(button03);

  if (buttonState01){
    time = 3000;
    while(time > 0){
      if (buttonState02){
        Serial.println("Points");
      }
      time--;
      Serial.println(time);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "The problem I am finding is that it doesn't detect when the button is pressed while the time is decreasing". That would be because you don't read the button while the time is decreasing. In addition, there is no signal de-bouncing anywhere, so this code will never work reliably unless you got some external RC low-pass filter in the hardware. Also, you need to enable internal pull resistors if there are none present externally.

Comment: the posted code is missing a lot of necessary statements.  Suggest reading: <https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/digitalRead> for a better understanding of 'button' handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the status of a button inside the while loop. Like this:

```
while(time > 0)
{
  buttonState02 = digitalRead(button02);
  if (buttonState02){
    Serial.println("Points");
  }
  time--;
  Serial.println(time);  
}
```

And in your code, there is no logic to add points to the score.

Answer (score 1):

A hardware interrupt would do exactly what you need.

Attach an interrupt routine to the pin your button is linked to,  and get it to set the 'score' variable.  Make sure you introduce some sort of timeout to avoid button-bounce (I.e. set LastTimeIncremented when you increase the score, and only increment score if LastTimeIncremented is more than 1 second ago)

This way the score will always be set regardless of what else the program may be doing.

Information on this can be found in the Arduino https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt

The example on that page would do exactly what you want, just replace 'blink' with 'incrementScore' and you're pretty much done

```
 const byte ledPin = 13;
 const byte interruptPin = 2;
 int score = 0;
 int increment = 1;


void setup() {
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), incScore, RISING);
}

void loop() {
   digitalWrite(ledPin, state);
}

void incScore() {
   score = score+increment;
   // add anti-bounce functionality here
}
```